# array_merge with multidimensional arrays in php

Tags: php, arrays, multidimensional-array

using this `foreach` loop :

```
foreach($course_presence as $key => $value){
    $presence_arr[$value['student']] = array();
    array_push($presence_arr[$value['student']],$value); 
}
```

i create array  that its keys are the students id's . student id =  `$value['student']`.(1,2,3...)

`$value` has the following structure exp:
`array(3) { ["student"]=> string(1) "1" ["course"]=> string(4) "1111" ["date"]=> string(19) "2016-03-17 10:25:00"` }

why if this loop executes 10 times for two different ids i dont get all the arrays for each student id?

EXAMPLE:
in my case currently the loop iterates over this data:

```
array(3) { ["student"]=> string(1) "1" ["course"]=> string(4) "1111" ["date"]=> string(19) "2016-03-17 10:25:00" }
 array(3) { ["student"]=> string(1) "5" ["course"]=> string(4) "1111" ["date"]=> string(19) "2016-01-01 10:00:00" }
 array(3) { ["student"]=> string(1) "5" ["course"]=> string(4) "1111" ["date"]=> string(19) "2016-01-22 00:00:00" } 
array(3) { ["student"]=> string(1) "5" ["course"]=> string(4) "1111" ["date"]=> string(19) "2016-02-14 00:00:00" }
 array(3) { ["student"]=> string(1) "5" ["course"]=> string(4) "1111" ["date"]=> string(19) "2016-02-28 00:00:00" }
 array(3) { ["student"]=> string(1) "1" ["course"]=> string(4) "1111" ["date"]=> string(19) "2016-02-14 14:00:00" }
 array(3) { ["student"]=> string(1) "5" ["course"]=> string(4) "1111" ["date"]=> string(19) "2016-03-27 00:00:00" }
```

and var_dump of the `presence_arr` is this:

```
    array(2) { 
[1]=> array(1) { [0]=> array(3) { ["student"]=> string(1) "1" ["course"]=> string(4) "1111" ["date"]=> string(19) "2016-02-14 14:00:00" } }
 [5]=> array(1) { [0]=> array(3) { ["student"]=> string(1) "5" ["course"]=> string(4) "1111" ["date"]=> string(19) "2016-01-03 05:00:00" } } }
```

as you cans the merge ran over  and replaced the value in each index instead of merging? ani idea what causing that?
thx

Comment: I think your problem is in the `$presence_arr[$value['student']] = array();` line. `$presence_arr[$value['student']]` gets assigned to a new empty array. If there was already any data in `$presence_arr[$value['student']]` it is removed and replaced with an empty array, preventing any merging from happening.

Comment: youre right...quite stupid of me..thx